# Ansible playbook to outputs a role variable and information about your operating system

Tags: ansible

using ansible 2.8 or newer to:

I need to render a template to my Desktop that outputs a role variable and information about my operating system

I need the variable to have a default value in the role and be overridden by the playbook

Running the playbook should look something like this as outpout

localhost                  : ok=2    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$ cat ~/Desktop/my-template.txt

My custom variable is test1234

My operating system in Darwin localhost 18.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Tue Aug 20 16:57:14 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.271.2~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Any help will be much appreciated I am still learning , Thank in advanced.

This is what I have so far

My jinja2 file is : my-template.j2

```
<center>
   <h1> My custom variable is {{ test_file }}</h1>
   <h3> My operating system in {{ uname_a }}</h3>
</center>
</html>


I need to render a template to my Desktop that outputs a role variable and information about my operating system

I need the variable to have a default value in the role and be overridden by the playbook

My playbook look like this:
```

---

- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  become: yes
  vars:
  test_file : "test1234"
  uname_a : "Darwin localhost 19.6.0 Darwin ,,,,"

  tasks:

  - name: "my-role : get os details"
    template:
    src: my-templates.j2
    dest: /Desktop/my-template.txt

Comment: What's the question? Show us what you've tried so far and explain where specifically you're having difficulty.

Comment: ```---

 - hosts: 127.0.0.1
   become: yes
   vars: 
     test_file : "test1234"
     uname_a : "Darwin localhost ........"

   tasks:
     - name: "my-role : get os details"
       template:
         src: my-templates.j2
         dest: /Desktop/my-template.txt```

Comment: That's my playbook and my Template look like :

Comment: <html>
<center>
   <h1> My custom variable is {{ test_file }}</h1>
   <h3> My operating system in {{ uname_a }}</h3>
</center>
</html>

Comment: How can I  have a default value in the role and be overridden by the playbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of the kernel version in the template dynamically you should use the output of `uname -a` command instead of setting it as a variable.

Example template `my-template.txt.j2`:

```
My custom variable is {{ test_file }}
My operating system is {{ uname_a }}
```

Though you mentioned about a role, I don't see it being used in the playbook you have shown...

So example playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    test_file: 'test1234'

  tasks:
  - name: get kernel version
    command: 'uname -a'
    register: uname_result
  - name: save to variable
    set_fact:
      uname_a: '{{ uname_result.stdout }}'
  - name: write os details to file
    template:
      src: 'my-template.txt.j2'
      dest: '/tmp/my-template.txt'
```

Renders the below contents in `/tmp/my-template.txt` (I am using a Linux box):

```
My custom variable is test1234
My operating system is Linux linux-2hyj 3.4.6-2.10-desktop #1
```

That said, you should prefer use of [automatic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html) provided by Ansible when possible. Possible facts you could use are:

- `ansible_os_family`
- `ansible_distribution`
- `ansible_kernel`

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated